# How can I search necessary information in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

You need to find all the words where the attribute category="ps" indicates that this is a proper name (in this case, the designation "nprop") from XML-file. How can I do it?
Thank you!
XML_file:

```
</tier>
      <tier id="ps" speaker="MiYA" category="ps" type="a" display-name="ps" >
         <event start="T0" end="T1">nprop</event>
         <event start="T1" end="T2">v</event>
         <event start="T2" end="T3">v</event>
 </tier>
```

I was trying to program:

```cs
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\Vera\\Desktop\\ВИКУСИК\\ПРОЕКТ\\извлечение имен\\извлечение имен\\bin\\Debug\\MiYA_196X_ILivedInMineevka_nar.exb");
            XElement root = XElement.Load(reader);
            XmlNameTable nameTable = reader.NameTable;
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
            nsmanager.AddNamespace("ps", "nprop");
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = root.XPathSelectElements("./tier", nsmanager);
                Console.WriteLine( elements);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How does xml file look like? What have you tried so far? It looks like a homework

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please read also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @OguzOzgul, I don't understand how can I get access to layers "ps" and "nprop". Are these layers nodes?

Comment: Share the xml content please. At least share the standard if the xml file follows a standard (like soap) Share your source code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Victoria, while asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. 
Please provide the following: 
(1) XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1.

Comment: @OguzOzgul see my editions, please

Comment: Do you need to get the value "nprop" or something else? Like the "start" and "end" attributes?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I need to get the value "start"  and "end" attributes if id="ps" and the <event> nsprop</event>

Comment: Based on your code, it seems that your XML has namespaces. Please edit your post and share with us your real XML, not just a fragment of it. Also, where is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

To get the start and end attributes of the element `<tier id="ps" ...><event>nprop</event>` or `<tier category="ps" ...><event>nprop</event>`:

```
XmlDocument meetingNotes = new XmlDocument();
meetingNotes.Load("C:\\Users\\Vera\\Desktop\\ВИКУСИК\\ПРОЕКТ\\извлечение имен\\извлечение имен\\bin\\Debug\\MiYA_196X_ILivedInMineevka_nar.exb");

XmlNodeList nPropEventElementsByCategory =
    meetingNotes.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//tier[@category='ps']/event[text() = 'nprop']");

XmlNodeList nPropEventElementsById =
    meetingNotes.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//tier[@id='ps']/event[text() = 'nprop']");

foreach (XmlElement nPropEventElementById in nPropEventElementsById)
{
    // Print out the start and end attributes
    Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}, End: {1}",
        nPropEventElementById.Attributes["start"].Value,
        nPropEventElementById.Attributes["end"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq (XDocument)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string[] words = doc.Descendants()
                .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes()
                    .Where(y => (string)y == "ps")
                    .Select(y => y.Name.LocalName))
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```